# Как переименовать все файлы из подпапок с помощью Python

Tags: python, файлы, gitlab, репозиторий, rename

Всем привет!
Я начинающий программист, немного пишу на Python.

На данный момент появилась задача от руководства: скачать наш репозиторий с GitLab и переименовать все файлы.

Мной был скачен репозиторий внутри которого находится много папок внутри которых тоже есть папки и внутри этих папок лежат файлы (папка - внутри которой лежит папка - внутри которой лежит папка - внутри которой лежит файл)
Файлы имеют следующий тип наименований
MSWH0**2**031_10.254.3.81;
MSWH0**2**065_10.254.3.207;
MSWH0**2**066_10.254.3.208.cfg;
MSWH0**2**035_10.254.3.110.cfg;
MSWH0**2**056_10.254.3.193.bin
и т.п.

В итоге наименование файлов должно быть таким:
MSWH0**1**031_10.254.3.81;
MSWH0**1**065_10.254.3.207;
MSWH0**1**066_10.254.3.208.cfg;
MSWH0**1**035_10.254.3.110.cfg;
MSWH0**1**056_10.254.3.193.bin
- везде первая 2 меняется на 1.

Файлов очень много, поэтому переименовывать в ручную нет смыла, это займет очень много времени.

Прошу вас подсказать как это сделать.

Comment: Приведите в вопросе собственные попытки решения

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212643/python-recursive-folder-read

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Как создать [mcve]?

Comment: В линуксе это можно провернуть через MidnightCommander встроенными средствами переименования по маске.

Comment: На данный момент есть идея решения :1. Нужно вывести весь список файлов из всех папок
2. С помощью цикла перебрать каждое название и когда в названии после 0 встречается 2 заменить ее на 1
3. Насколько я понял нужно использовать библиотеку OS

Comment: МОЕ РЕШЕНИЕ: import os
tree = os.walk('D:\KAT\Switch_bacup')
for i in tree:
    print(i)

Answer (score 1):

1. Получаете имена файлов
2. Потом к каждому имени применяете

   ```
    nameFile = nameFile.replace('2','1',1)
   ```

Более подробно о методе replace: https://pythonz.net/references/named/string.replace/

Comment: как получить имена файлов из папок

Comment: @Saiber Soxov, начинающий программист - должен уметь пользоваться поисковиком. <https://coderoad.ru/31222137/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-python>

Answer (score 0):

Получилось решить поставленную задачу с помощью следующего скрипта:

```
for dirname, _, files in os.walk('D:\GitLAB\conf\Switch_bacup'):
    for old_name in files:
        new_name = old_name.replace('2', '1',1)
        if old_name != new_name:
            os.rename(os.path.join(dirname, old_name),os.path.join(dirname,new_name))
```